# How to read a specific word in text file and use a condition statement to do something

Tags: java, netbeans, try-catch, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I'm new to coding in java. Can anyone help me with my codes? I'm currently making a program where you input a string in a jTextArea, and if the input word(s) matches the one in the text file then it will then do something.

For example: I input the word 'Hey' then it will print something like "Hello" when the input word matches from the text file.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Here's my code:

```
String line;
    String yo;
    yo = jTextArea2.getText();

    try (
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("readme.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    ) 
    {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if (yo.equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
                System.out.print("Hello");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ArfArf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use equals for line because a line contain many words. You have to modify it to search the index of the word in a line.

```
       try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("readme.txt");
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.toLowerCase();
                yo = yo.toLowerCase();
                if (line.indexOf(yo) != -1) {
                    System.out.print("Hello");
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
```

Comment: please remove the line  = br.readLine() from the codes since the line is assign in the while((line = br.readLine)).  If you do so , some lines will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

since you are new in java , I would suggest you to take some time to study java 8 which enable to write more clean codes. below is the solution write in java 8, hope can give a kind of help

```
        String yo = jTextArea2.getText();
        //read file into stream, 
        try (java.util.stream.Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("readme.txt"))) {

            List<String> matchLines = stream.filter((line) -> line.indexOf(yo) > -1).collect(Collectors.toList()); // find all the lines contain the text
            matchLines.forEach(System.out::println); // print out all the lines contain yo

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String yo = "some word";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")); // path to file
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            if (scanner.nextLine().contains(yo)) { // check if line has your finding word
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
        }
    }
}
```